# How to capture email click activity into custom data extension in Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, email-template, ssjs

I am sending emails to users using journey builder. These emails have yes or no buttons. I want to send email based on these buttons. That means when click yes send abc email & when click no send xyz email. Clicking the yes button in the email should not redirect to another page. How to store values ​​of yes and no button in custom DE when clicked

Answer (score 2):

All email clicks are stored in the [Click data view](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5). By querying it, you will be able to find all the Subscriber Keys, who have clicked on a particular link. Firstly, you should add tracking alias to your yes/no links:

```html
<a alias="Yes" href="www.example.com/yes">Oh yes!</a>
<a alias="No" href="www.example.com/no">Hell no!</a>
```

This will allow you to query the Click data view, for finding the yes/no clickers respectively:

```sql
SELECT
    click.SubscriberKey
    ,click.EventDate
FROM _Click AS click
WHERE click.LinkName = 'Yes'
```

```sql
SELECT
    click.SubscriberKey
    ,click.EventDate
FROM _Click AS click
WHERE click.LinkName = 'No'
```

You are writing:

> Clicking the yes button in the email should not redirect to another page.

This is not really possible, as all the links from the email will eventually need to point to some URL. If you want to capture Yes/No within the email itself, you could experiment with an [Interactive Email Form Block.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_interactive_email_form_block.htm&type=5)